# How to get the key dynamically in Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase

I have i Firebase data created like this :

[image]

I need to get the second object's ID. I tried to use getKey() method but its returned "Post" .. I want to get the unique ID.
I use this code to add values :

```
private DatabaseReference refposts;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    context = this;
    refposts = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts");
    Posts posts = new Posts();
    posts.setTitle("Title2");
    posts.setDesc("Desc2ً");
    posts.setWriter("user-1");
    refposts.child("Post").push().setValue(posts);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the solution :

```
            DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference("Posts/Post");

            // Attach a listener to read the data at our posts reference
            ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Posts  post = postSnapshot.getValue(Posts .class);
                        //postSnapshot.getKey(); THIS IS YOUR UNIQUE KEY
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                }
            });
```

Suggestion :

Don't : `refposts.child("Post").push().setValue(posts);`

Do's  : `refposts.push().setValue(posts);`

And then only use "Posts" for database reference.

---

To use Query :

```
DatabaseReference myRef= database.getReference("Posts/Post");
    Query query = myRef.orderByChild("title").equalTo("Title2");
                query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
```

Comment: Thanks its works. But I don't want to get all keys I just need to get the specific key for title == "Title2".

Comment: @MKJParekh how we can do this in JavaScript for web ? I'm stuck at the similar question but in JavaScript.